# Getting Crashed on my debian gnome

Tags: debian, gnome3

In My Debian system Gnome with crashed. Using alt+ctrl+f1 I get the terminal.Which process should I kill and start to make it working again??

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do a restart.

With modern hardware you should be able to simply press (or press and hold) the power button.

Alternatively if you have a console that is responsive you can do:

```
sudo reboot
```

If that has an issue, you could also try adding the `--force` option like so:

```
sudo reboot --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Display-manager. `systemctl restart $(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager | cut -d / -f 4)`. If you know your display-manager start him directly. Example  `systemctl restart gdm3`

Check if your hardware is powerfull enough for gnome3. Problems with gnome-session are logged in `$HOME/.xsession-errors`, after restart from the display-manager in `$HOME/.xsession-errors.old`